# Animating eye texture in a head mesh

Tags: animation, texturing, game-engine

I'm trying to animate a mesh with different eye textures but it's not working.

[image: mesh with texture to animate]

This is a texture made by me to animate but I still couldn't figure out how to do it. I've seen tutorials on the internet but they don't work to me.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BopkonvbCEE ?

Comment: Simillar yes, i´ve already watched that video but i cant make it work with my face mesh:S

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an addon called ***Animall*** to animate the texture.
[image]

### CYCLES

1. Activate an AnimAll add-on (File--> User Preferences--> Addons--> AnimAll). It'll be displayed in the tools menu in the 'Animation' section.

[image]

2. Setup the image texture in the Node Editor. Enter the "Edit Mode"and unwrap the mesh (press U in 3d window) using the Project from view.

[image]

3. In UV/Image Editor place the UV island on the desired part of the image texture (note that you have to make perfect spaces between images in graphics program. In this case the images have 200 px of space between them).

[image]

4. Check the 'UVs' box and insert the first keyframe (clicking 'Insert').

[image]

5. Go to the next frame (right arrow), place the UV island on the next part of the image texture (in this case i go 200 units along x axis) and inesert the keyframe again. Repeat this process moving right.

[image]

6. Place the UV island in the lower row (in this case I move the uv island -600 units along x axis and -200 units along y axis)

[image]

7. Continue the proces and position the UV island on the last image part (of course the moving patern could be different). Go to the 'Object Mode' and play the animation (alt+A).

[image]

8.- Select all keyframes on the dopesheet (or Graph editor) and set them to **Constant**

[image]

9. You can also prepare the texture like this, so it will be easier to jump between images. Remember about doing perfect spacing between them.

[image]

10. Go to NLA Editor, change the action name (CTRL+LMB) and click the 'double arrow' icon.

[image]

11. Now you have your 'blink animation' in one block and you can place it wherever you like on the timeline.

[image]

Hope I helped.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### BLENDER INTERNAL RENDER

I'm adding an update, since Warianos wants to know how to do the same thing in Blender Internal. So here it goes:

1. Select the mesh you want to have an animated texture on it, and in *Shading* panel change the *Material Mode* from ***Multitexture*** to ***GLSL***. Add a lamp (a sun lamp for example), so you'll be able to see the texture when you apply it.

[image]

2. With the object selected in *Object Mode* go to the *Materials Panel*. Add the material. Set the *Diffuse* and *Specular* values if you want.

[image]

3. Go to the *Textures Panel*, set the texture type to ***Image or Movie***, then click the *Open* button in *Image panel* and load your image.

[image]

4. In *Mapping* panel set the Coordinates to **UV**.

[image]

5. In 3d window set the *Viewport Shading* to ***Texture***

[image]

6. Load an image in *Uv/Image Editor* window. Unwrap the mesh using *Project from View* option. Enable an *AnimAll addon* and check the *Uvs* box.

[image]

7. Now the process looks like in my previous answer. You press *Insert* in AnimAll panel and add a keyframe. Then you go to other frame, change the Uv island's position and press *Insert* again.

[image]
[image]

8. Being in *Object Mode*, with the *Viewport Shading* set to *Texture* you can now play an animation to check out how it looks like. If you don't want the smooth transition between images you may set the *Curve Interpolation type* to ***Constant***, by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> in graph editor window (as Cegaton suggested in his answer).

[image]

Hope it is what you wanted to know.

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear that :). Could you please mark this answer as useful?

Comment: I guess i´ve already done that:s humm isnt it the "right" icon?

Comment: Gonzo do u know which nodes are required in blender render to make the trasaction from frame to.frame not smooth? I mean only showing where at x frame is the selection. U did this in cicles but i would like to know if its possible in normal render or game render. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot Gonzo really! And im sorry for taking you time

Comment: Gonzo let me ask you one more last thing, if i export this animation for unity for example, it should do as done here right?

Comment: It should work. Sorry, but I don't know for sure. You have to give it a try. See this tutorial: http://cgcookie.com/unity/2011/12/05/exporting-characters-from-blender/ It explains how to export all the animation data and textures to Unity. You may also ask another question here. Maybe someone knows if it is working.

Comment: Oh, and if it works, please let me know. I am curious.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thanks for this write up.

Answer (score 8):

Using a UV project modifier you can use an empty to control the mapping of the texture.

On your UV unwrapped object create a material that uses the UVs

[image]

Load your image in the background of the 3D view.
Add an empty and scale it to be the size of your picture. The numbers for the scale will help you determine the offset between each of the different expressions for your character.

[image]

Select your object and add a **[UV project modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Modify/UV_Project)**. On the modifier set your image, use image override, and set the Empty as projector.

[image]

Now the texture of your object is controlled by the empty. If you move it around you can use different parts of your image as texture.

Move the empty and create different keyframes for different expressions.

On the curve editor set the interpolation between keyframes to "constant"

[image]

[image]

Example blend [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32570)

Comment: Would this work in Unity? Also, do you still have the source file?