# Texture Changing with Keyframes

Tags: texturing, uv, keyframes

I have created UV textures for lip-syncing, but I do not know how to change the textures with keyframes. So say I want to go from a neutral face to a transition face on the next 5 frames to a speaking face. How would I do this?

Edit:
I am using Blender Render. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: @NoviceInDisguiseGraphics what? lol

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for but it may help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh