# How to animate textures in blender internal and control them

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, drivers

Is it possible to animate textures and then control them with a bone or empty? I want to animate eye textures blinking and looking in different directions etc. by of course drawing the frames. is there a way to control them like shape keys with bones and drivers?

Comment: One of the Gooseberry artists showed how to do exactly that: https://gooseberry.blender.org/caterpillar-making-of-animating-uvs/

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh/18446#18446

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beTOy-dwOOc

Answer (score 1):

You could put a Driver on the Mapping/Offset of an image texture that copies its value from a controlling empty or bone.

Here is a screenshot that shows such a rig.  Notice that the X offset is purple (meaning it is controlled by a driver) and you can see the driver in the curves window configured to copy the minimum value from the Empty object's X Location in World space.

[image: screenshot of driver controlling texture's X offset]