# Need help with animating textures using AnimAll (texture moving is somehow visible during animation)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, add-on, keyframes

I'm trying to animate eye blinking with help from this tutorial:

[Animating eye texture in a head mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh)

and while doing everything the tut mentions, the outcome somehow doesn't look good. The problem is that the texture moving is visible in animation, as shown on this screen:

[image]

Anyone knows how to solve this? D:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default blender will use Bezier interpolation mode between keyframes, creating a smooth transition from one keyframe to the next.

In this case you want no interpolation, you need the placement to remain **constant** and then make a sudden change from one keyframe to the next.

In the dope sheet editor (or the graph editor), select all of the keyframes for the texture and set **[Interpolation Mode](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves.html?highlight=interpolation#interpolation-mode)** to **constant** (the shortcut for interpolation menu is <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help! Didn't really know that interpolation can be modified in Blender D: good to learn that it's almost as efficient as in adobe AE :D

Comment: In my opinion is better than AE ;)