# (Blender Internal) Texture Switching?

Tags: animation

I want to switch between textures, kind of like key framing them, and i tried this by clicking on the texture check mark, inserting a key frame, scrolling down further on the timeline, and inserting another keyframe, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do this and is there a way to make the texture switch a smooth transition?

Comment: Check this thread: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: That is with a texture that's one whole image. I have 3 completely different textures that are different images.

Comment: Just join them in any graphic software and you're good to go with this method. Make things simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the use_texture property should change textures but will give a sudden change not a nice transition between textures.

The influence settings of the texture can be animated allowing a texture to gradually replace another texture.

[image: animated texture layer]