# Animatable lines drawn on sphere

Tags: animation

I'm trying to bring a  character created by my niece to life. The head of the character is a sphere, and the eyes and mouth should look like they are line drawings on the sphere.  I want to be able to animate the mouth and eye movements so that it has the look of a 2D cartoon projected onto the sphere. I'm new to Blender. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: You mean like grease pencil animations?

Comment: Yeah, either use a texture animation as described in that link or do it with actual geometry, like a *Grease Pencil* stroke, or an animated bezier curve over your sphere.