# 2-D movement in blender?

Tags: animation

so I'm pretty new at Blender, and I was curious about how you can make an object (the controlled object) to flip in the other direction without having to face the camera to do so. Like instant flipping everytime i press a direction. If someone could help, that would be cool.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is not quite clear, do you want to animate texture appearance ? Maybe related question - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: If you are referring to animation/game engine interaction then all I think you need to do is 'flip' said object very fast, as in a sub-frame timespan

Answer (score 0):

By flipping, do you mean mirroring ?

In that case you can do it whatever the view you have.
Just press *Ctrl+M* and next *X*, *Y* or *Z* for the mirror axis (in world coordinates)

Press a second time *X*, *Y* or *Z* for the mirror axis to switch to local coordinates.