# Animation sequence of PNG file

Tags: animation

I have a PNG file which is like a film strip of an animation all in 1 file.

Is is possible in Blender to render this file to make the animation work?

https://s13.postimg.org/9y5hbgj5j/humans_inhabitants_female_1b2122ef25431178a7f863.png

If not does anyone know how? The game it's from seems to do it and I've seen other models + animations work in programs like Blender / Photoshop before.

Probably cant but thought I'd ask.

Thanks

Comment: You can do that either by animating the UV coordinates of the object , or alternatively break the png strip into a frame sequence

Comment: UV coordinates? I'm new to Blender I dont have a clue about it. Could you add a little more to that comment?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh/18446#18446

Comment: Cegaton's link seems to cover it pretty well, if you have any further questions feel free to as or post a new question.