# how to change Pikachu's expression

Tags: modeling

I downloaded this file.
https://clara.io/view/5636d5e5-863f-48a7-8c4e-ec5e306add92/image

Then, maybe there is some eye pattern.
[image]

But, I don't know how to change eye. How to change? Thank you.

- supplementation -

[Animating eye texture in a head mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh)

In this topic, the facial expression image is displayed large, but I do not know where this image is in the first place.How can I make the same screen as this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a texture node in your materials 
Are you using Cycles render ?

Cycles render - Solution: 
You may follow the following steps

Add two materials on eye, one for eye base and one for the eye ball
[image]

Modify the eye ball material as shown below
[image]

Then un wrap the faces ( by pressing U key) as shown below
[image]

Comment: Thank you for comment. The present, I use blender render. But, I can use each render.

Comment: Please have a kind look on the updated answer :)

Comment: I have a question. Is your answer mean to make eyes myself? If that's the case, it is different from my will. This pikachu probably have 7 eyes pattern.  
 Is not it perhaps to switch in some way?

Comment: In this case my solution will not work for you :(

Comment: Oh, I see. But thank you very much for comment! I am so happy. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, you may try this if you like: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: Thank you for suggest. But in this topic, the facial expression image is displayed large, but I do not know where this image is in the first place. Do you know how can I make the same screen as this?

Comment: I guess you can use same setup only on your eyes. it will be same as I set up above for the texture