# How do I animate texture mapping on a model?

Tags: animation, texturing

I am trying to animate this model I have, but I want to add blinking. This model has all the eye textures on one image, and I need to animate the mapping. I have looked for tutorials on this but all of them solve a problem I don't have.

[image]

When I try to press "I" on "Location," it gives me a "failed to resolve path to property" error. If you need the model, I can send you a download link to it.
Thank you to who ever tries to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show your node setup? Inserting a keyframe like so works for me, maybe there is somethign else wrong in your file.

Comment: My node setup for the texture only has 3 nodes to output the texture on the mesh.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh Solved my problem, thanks to who ever pointed that out.