# How do i make 2D eyelids?

Tags: animation, materials

So i was remaking my characters to have better eyelids with 2d images of the eyelids, but they won't show up because the eye texture was in front[image].

I tried moving it the eyelids in front but they block the eyes even though its transplant. I also tried looking up videos of how to do it. But they didn't have one that did. How do you do it?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh/18446#18446

Comment: possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36748/how-do-you-animate-image-texture-materials-in-blender-cycles-with-keyframes/36793#36793

Comment: These arn't really what i wanted....WAY different to what i am talking about. And i don't want to use cycles as well since its take about a half an hour to render for me.